# A definition of for-each

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

> **Exercise 2.23**
>
> The procedure for-each
>   is similar to map. It takes as
>   arguments a procedure and a list of
>   elements. However, rather than forming
>   a list of the results, for-each just
>   applies the procedure to each of the
>   elements in turn, from left to right.
>   The values returned by applying the
>   procedure to the elements are not used
>   at all -- for-each is used with
>   procedures that perform an action,
>   such as printing. For example,
>
> ```
> (for-each (lambda (x) (newline) (display x))
>           (list 57 321 88))
> 57
> 321
> 88
> ```
>
> The value returned by the call to
>   for-each (not illustrated above) can
>   be something arbitrary, such as true.
>   Give an implementation of for-each.

I wrote the following:

```
(define (for-each l f)
  (f (car l))
  (when (> (length l) 1) (for-each (cdr l) f)))
```

Is this a good answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Your function needs to handle the empty list too. If your implementation supports `unless`, use this:

```
(define (for-each f l)
  (unless (null? l)
    (f (car l))
    (for-each f (cdr l))))
```

Otherwise, the R5RS-compatible version would be:

```
(define (for-each f l)
  (cond ((not (null? l))
         (f (car l))
         (for-each f (cdr l)))))
```

Granted, the implicit `begin` behaviour of `cond` is not explained until Chapter 3. So if you want to avoid using that, here's a similar version that uses `let` to simulate `begin`:

```
(define (for-each f l)
  (cond ((not (null? l))
         (let ()
           (f (car l))
           (for-each f (cdr l))))))
```

Now, here, too, the `let` body is an implicit `begin`. If you want to work around *that*, too, then bind the result of the side-effect to a dummy variable:

```
(define (for-each f l)
  (cond ((not (null? l))
         (let ((unused (f (car l))))
           (for-each f (cdr l))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution below relies on neither unless nor begin.  This seems somewhat desirable because neither of these procedures has been introduced in the text at this point.

```
(define (for-each proc items)
  (if (null? items)
    #t
    (if ((lambda (x) #t) (proc (car items)))
      (for-each proc (cdr items)))))
```

Comment: It's true that `begin` isn't introduced until chapter 3. However, `(let () ...)` (since `let`'s body has an implicit `begin`) is a better workaround for that than using the `(lambda (x) #t)` hack that you have, since the latter doesn't make clear that `(proc (car items))` is evaluated purely for side effects.